# Is it possible to clone a class in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, inheritance, single-sign-on, httpsession

I have this monolith JAR in my current web server configuration. The whole system was drawn in a way that you can't have separate web apps, everything runs around this big jar.

In the process of solving this, I'm trying to take out the sso authentication from the original security package (which I have the source code), the problem I'm dealing with is related to a Usuario class.

From what I understand, the original class will set a 'usuario' atribute, after getting the atributes from the tokenid

```
usuario = ssoUtil.getAtributosUsuario(tokenId);

httpSession.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
httpServletRequest.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
```

I changed the Usuario class to UsuarioSSO, and implemented the whole authentication thing as a global server filter -since it's a requirement of the project that it is impossible to publish anything on the server without authentication.

The actual Usuario class - the one that is set - is just a bunch of private variables, getters, setters and two methods  with the implementation of the classes Serializable and HttpSessionBindingListener.

The issue arises when any classes from the original INTL problem try to get the Usuario atributes from the httpSession:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: pathToClass.UsuarioSSO cannot be cast to intlPathToClass.Usuario
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get this cast to work. But it seems impossible to do a downcast, even thou both classes are identical.

Just FYI, I can change the INTL Usuario class at will, but I can't change the code that actually uses that class, everything would work fine if I could change all references to INTL Usuario to UsuarioSSO.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't UsuarioSSO extend Usuario?

Comment: Why duplicate the code? Move original `Usuario` class from big jar to a separate jar. Then use that jar in the existing application and your new filter.

Comment: If I move the class to to a separate jar I still need to use the old package naming conventions, or change all references to the original Usuario class.

Comment: If I have UsuarioSSO extend Usuario I need to make the Usuario class available on server level, instead of app level. Actually that's a decent solution, but I would have to keep the original package names so other code won't break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Erickson's comments.  You can move the class to a separate jar.  You can still preserve the original package name.

Two jars can use the same package names.  The only time it gets weird is if those packages have the same classes.  But that should be a problem if you move the Usuario class.

Comment: This is one solution, but it feels unnecessary. Isn't there a way to do this without having to move the class to a separate jar?

Comment: Do you want to do a deep clone on the INTL Usuario object and supply the clone to UsuarioSSO?

Comment: I wanted to supply the clone to INTL Usuario.

Comment: Well, until I can find a better solution, I'm following this. UsuarioSSO extends Usuario, it seems to solve most of the problems, except a colleague who keeps whining about the whole INTL package name.